# simpleMDE: Add functionality to insert text programatically at cursor position

Tags: javascript, html, simplemde

I am using [simplemde-markdown-editor](https://github.com/sparksuite/simplemde-markdown-editor) library and I want to be able to insert text programmatically at the cursor position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var simplemde = new SimpleMDE();
```

After Create instance of `simpleMDE` you can do this:

```js
var pos = simplemde.codemirror.getCursor();
simplemde.codemirror.setSelection(pos, pos);
simplemde.codemirror.replaceSelection("YOUR_TEXT");
```